# Reason for receiving negative reputation when no down votes

Tags: discussion, support, reputation

I asked [this question](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/29498/how-can-i-slice-and-modulate-samples-in-logic-like-abletons-slice-to-midi-featu) and something happened, because there are no down votes anywhere within the thread, yet I received -2 reputation for it.

What is going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have both an up vote and a down vote on the question. You *should* be +3 on the tally (+5 up, -2 down). You'll be able to see the +/- vote breakdown (instead of just the aggregated count) when you reach 750 reputation.

As for why the down vote, I really don't know.